# SQL Error 1064 Not sure

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying a new way of inserting data into a SQL. I am getting this error

```
insert into tracking_clients set /   agreement_type = 'Purchase' , existing_client = 'Yes' , 
sales_rep = '1'
Array ( [agreement_type] => Purchase [existing_client] => Yes [sales_rep] => 1 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near '/   agreement_type = 'Purchase' , 
existing_client = 'Yes' , sales_rep = ' at line 2mysql err no : 1064
```

I use a form with action POST

In my submit page I use the following

```
//Drawn from Form Information used to Update Database
$sub1 = $_REQUEST['agreement_type'];
$sub2 = $_REQUEST['existing_client'];
$sub3 = $_REQUEST['sales_rep'];

update_lbs($sub1, $sub2, $sub3, $sub4,....); //Not full string posted here
function update_lbs($sub1, $sub2, $sub3, $sub4,.....)

{
  global $host;
  global $username;
  global $password;
  global $db_name;
  //Insert if dates is required
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg'); //Global Time one for South Africa
 $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date = date("Y-m-d") ;
$time = date("H:i:s");
$insertSuccessful = false;
$new_msisdn = '0' . substr($msisdn, 2); //Not Sure If this is required in normal SET command
if ($con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) {
    if (mysql_select_db($db_name))      
//First Database Insert change table name as required
        $sql = "insert into tracking_clients  set    
        agreement_type =  '".$sub1."' ,
        existing_client =  '".$sub2."' ,
        sales_rep = '".$sub3."',

                    sub_date = '".$date."'" //Last of the code for SET
        ;    
if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
            $insertSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            echo $sql;
            print_r($_POST);
            echo "\n" . mysql_error($con);
            echo "mysql err no : " . mysql_errno($con);
        }
```

I am not sure what would be causing this error at all. I know this question is a common one but reading thru the other awnsers I am not getting the error

Comment: mysql `insert` has another syntax.

Comment: I have found my error. In my initial code I had a typing error the SET command as above is correct but I had a / in front         agreement_type =  '".$sub1."' , causing syntax error's Typo on My side thanks guys

Comment: Be careful with user input - you appear to have several SQL injection vulnerabilities here. Always escape `$_REQUEST` values with `mysql_real_escape_string()` before using them, or better yet switch to a library that offers parameterisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a tab characters beetween "set" and "agreement_type"

Comment: Whitepsace shouldn't cause an error if everything else is okay.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using mysql here. The insert statement doesn't use `set` it simply inserts the values.

Something like this:

```
insert into yourTable (val1, val2, val3)
```

or

```
insert into yourTable (col1, col2, col3) values (val1, val2, val3)
```

not

```
insert into yourTable set col1=val1 etc...
```

Comment: Yup, and the second one is to be preferred over the first one, since it will still work if you change the order of the columns, or insert new columns.